# Transfer data from .msg files to excel

Tags: python, excel, outlook, transfer, msg

i got a lot of .msg files which contain information of an mail-form (name, telefon, mail etc.) of my website all saved in one folder. I'm trying to transfer all the information of the .msg-files into one excel file. As there are a lot of .msg files (like 150) I would like to automate the process.

Is there an easy way via python to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: So which part are you having problems with? Enumerating and processing files in a folder? Reading the data from the MSG files? Exporting the data to Excel?

Comment: firstly, reading data from the msg files

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Application.Session.OpenSharedItem` to open an MSG file.